# 'NoneType' object is not iterable, paginator

Tags: django, pagination

I have a problem with my pagination in django. I got the message

> 'NoneType' object is not iterable, paginator

after analysing the code below, i thing that it is the qset variable which is getting the "None value". Why, i don't understand.

```
def recherche(request):   
    if request.method == "GET":

        search_etat = request.GET.get('etat')

        search_cat = request.GET.get('categorie') #and :

        qset = None

        if search_etat == 'tout':

            if search_cat!='0': 

                qset = (
                   Q(type=search_cat) &
                   Q(disponiblite ='Oui')

                )


        resultat = House.objects.filter(qset)

        paginator = Paginator(resultat, 2)
        page = request.GET.get('page')

        try:
            resul = paginator.page(page)

            except PageNotAnInteger:

            resul = paginator.page(1)

        except EmptyPage:

            result = paginator.page(paginator.num_pages)


    return render(request,'resultat.html',{'result':result})
```

Comment: Please post the FULL traceback

Answer (score 0):

Probably the problem is here:

```
qset = None

    if search_etat == 'tout':

        if search_cat!='0': 

            qset = (
               Q(type=search_cat) &
               Q(disponiblite ='Oui')

            )
```

Here the `qset`'s value doesn't change in the `if` block in later part of the code. So when you filter like `House.objects.filter(qset)` it throws the error.

So the probable solution should be like:

```
if search_etat == 'tout':
        if search_cat!='0': 
            qset = (
               Q(type=search_cat) &
               Q(disponiblite ='Oui')
            )

if qset is not None:
    resultat = House.objects.filter(qset)
else:    
    resultat = House.objects.none()
```

Comment: i already done it, i have nothing like result. but on the second page, i must have an other result. I have in my database 4 house, i have 2 on the first page, on the second with your solution, the error message desappear but i have nothing. why the qset take None like value

Comment: In url parameter of web browser, you must have 'etat' and 'categorie' like this: `192.168.0.1:8000/?etat=tout&categorie=dummy_category`. In 2nd page, check that in url if u have such parameters.

Comment: no just /?page=2 like in django documentation. sample on paginator don't talk about having  something like 192.168.0.1:8000/?etat=tout&categorie=dummy_category

Comment: well, your code says that you must have etat and categorie (for viewing House in template) in ur url parameter. So, you should test if your view is working properly like this:/?page=2&etat=tout&categories=some_category

Answer (score 0):

ok, i think i understand, i add ?etat=tout&categorie=dummy_category in the template html page on the next like this

```
{% if form.has_next %}

<a href="?page={{ form.next_page_number }}&etat={{ tout }}&categorie={{ categorie }}"> >> </a>

               {% endif %}
```

and a second return

```
    try:
        resul = paginator.page(page)

        except PageNotAnInteger:

        resul = paginator.page(1)

    except EmptyPage:

        result = paginator.page(paginator.num_pages)

    return render(request,'resultat.html',{'result':result,'etat':etat,'categorie':categorie})

return render(request,'resultat.html',{'result':result})
```

is it a good way? but it is working

Comment: I can't say if it is a good way. But if it works, than it should be fine, if you think.